# tf.cond() gets stuck on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I am trying to freeze some layers after some epochs during training. For which I am using tf.cond like this:

```
self._train_op = tf.cond(condition > 0,
                     lambda: optimizer.minimize(
                         self._loss, name="optimizer",
                         global_step=global_step),
                     lambda: optimizer.minimize(
                         self._loss, name="optimizer_2",
                         global_step=global_step,
                         var_list = [v for v in
                                     tf.trainable_variables()
                                     if 'domain' not in v.name])) #Freeze layers with domain in them
```

I change the value of condition during sess.run(), this code runs fine on a CPU but when I try to run it on a GPU it hangs forever. If I remove the tf.cond() and do

```
 self._train_op = optimizer.minimize(
 self._loss, name="optimizer",
 global_step=global_step)
```

Everything works fine. Does anyone know the reason why? How can I freeze some layers when some condition is met during training?

Comment: Any progress here? I am trying to use cond() to do something similar, that is to define optimizers. Though, most answers seems to divert you toward using a different function. I get stuck on the correct shape of the conditional tensor. It wants 0 and I pass rank 2.